How can I fix a crack between garage wall and ceiling?
This white concrete wall in my garage seems to not be sealed properly against the ceiling. I noticed 2 bubbles like this and when I tore into this one, I see light through it (seems to lead to the roof venting that runs along the edge of the roof).
I assume I could just fill it in and paint over it. Would that be the proper way to repair this? Does this mean that the whole seam on this wall is compromised?


White concrete? Where do you see that? What's the black area? Is that the ceiling? The fact that there's no vapor barrier or insulation there suggests a moisture problem. You'll need to resolve that before you repair the drywall joint or it'll recur.

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

That looks like water damage.  Do you have leaks?

I can’t directly comment under answers yet due to low reputation, but I’ll answer both here.
@Isherwood - The white is the cinderblock/concrete wall of the inside of my garage. The other side of the wall faces the outside where some moisture may come in, but doesn’t seem to be a leak or anything major. The roof overhangs on the outside wall, so the problem area isn’t directly exposed to the elements. The wall doesn’t have any steaks and no water was pooled in the paint bubble before I burst it. The black is the drywall ceiling, which aside from the paint bubbling off, it doesn’t seem to have much staining or any indication of water. It just seems like that seal did not do it’s job and it lacked sufficient mud.
@pdd the wall is an outer wall which is definitely concrete/cinderblocks. I’ll try cleaning the area before applying the mud and tape again. Thanks for the flat taping method link, I’ll check that out as well.

A picture from farther away would provide context for a better understanding .

This looks like drywall, not concrete.
If it is a drywall wall and a drywall ceiling, it looks like the paper tape joint between the wall and the ceiling failed due to insufficient mud between the tape and the drywall resulting in it separating.
You need to remove all the paper tape that has separated, as well as any loose bits of mud. If the wall side is not affected, you can tape just the ceiling using a method called 'flat tapping'. This would save you from having to deal with repairing the textured wall finish.

There's all kinds of clues there that moisture caused this, not dry tape.
